# Verifying PHP syntax in an entire directory, with xargs

Tags: php, syntax-error, xargs

`ls -1 *.php | xargs php -l` doesn't work, any clues why ? (it only checks the first file)

I am trying to detect parse errors in my whole application.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Came up with this, it is sufficient for my needs:

```
#!/bin/sh

for chave in `find . | grep .php` ; do 
    php -l $chave
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 php -l
```

This has the added bonus of working no matter what characters your filenames contain. Unfortunately I'm not sure why it's not working without the -L 1 part :(

Comment: The `-L 1` parameter makes it work in all of the above (with `ls` it only works for current directory nevertheless)! The `-print0` and `-0` args weren't necessary too.

Comment: They are not necessary when you are 100% sure that your file names don't contain "exotic" characters in them, that the shell might expand.

Comment: Add `-P 8` to the `xargs` command to enable parallel processing (in this case up to 8 invocations at once). It will still abort early and with the proper status code, but speeds it up a lot!
For example: `find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 -P 8 php -l`.

Answer (score 3):

Only print the once that fails:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 php -l | grep -v 'No syntax errors detected in ./'
```